# Force Download with PHP - Server Configuration?

Tags: php, types, download

I've searched alot for that and nothing works for me. The Problem is that the file got displayed in the Browser. It includes JSON, but is an .locx file (needed for an APP). No not my APP so i cant change that. I've tested so much variations of Content Types and Encodings, but nothing helped me out. That is my Code.

```
<?php
    function DownloadFile($file) {
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }

    }

    DownloadFile('storage/3-3-2.locx');
?>
```

Thanks for reading!

// UPDATE

It works on another Server, and as written in the comments the Script works very well, but what i have to change in the server configuration that it works for me too?

Comment: Your code works for me in both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Which browser are you testing with? For instance, I've found that Internet Explorer caches the Content-Type header and you have to restart it to get it to handle the content differently.

Comment: Works here also on Apache/FreeBSD, PHP 5.4.  I'd suggest possibly taking a look at your server configuration and MIME types....

Comment: @Kkinsey What i had to change in my Server Configuration that its working correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm not sure _exactly_; in my Apache (2.4), "locx" isn't listed in etc/apache24/mime.types nor in etc/apache24/magic, so I'm not sure what differences there might be between your server and my test.

I also wonder about your ob_clean() and flush() calls.  The manual for flush() mentions several caveats and quid pro quos that might give you cause to check if those calls have something to do with the issue (do you also need ob_flush(), are you serving via Win32, is mod_gzip enabled in Apache, & c)....

Comment: ob_clean(), flush() and multiple headers are not needed. I write it in for test purposes. On another Server it works. Dont know why actually. If i found a solution i will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens , while uploading the file.

While uploading the file encoding changed from utf8 to iso.